# Error in log file when using MY_Log to extend CI_Log

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I see the following error appearing throughout my application log file when it attempts to load MY_Log.

**ERROR - 26-03-2013 22:52:20—> Severity: Warning —> include_once(application/core/MY_Log.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory C:\dev\mysite\application\config\config.php 377**

My autoload file has the following:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('parser', 'session', 'log');
```

The MY_Log class is defined in application/libraries/MY_Log.php

```
class MY_Log extends CI_Log
```

The MY_Parser class, which is in application/libraries/MY_Parser.php loads fine.

```
class MY_Parser extends CI_Parser
```

When I debug the loader to see why Parser behaves differently from Log, it appears that it’s looking in application/core for MY_Log, but looks for (and finds) MY_Parser ok in application/libraries.

I am using CI 2.1.1

Any ideas why this difference?

Comment: Seeing as how there's nothing in the specified config file that should be loading a library, I'm going to assume that you've added an autoloader of some sort, and it is causing the problem. Post up its code if that's true.

Comment: Can you post what's in the line 377 of your application\config\config.php? Your error message suggests that there is an include_once in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 500 when calling get\_instance from a library in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350889/error-500-when-calling-get-instance-from-a-library-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

When you **EXTEND** a core library like `CI_Log` you **don't** autoload it. Why? Because CI_Log is automatically loaded by the CI Core. CI_Parser (not familiar with this one) is **not** a core library, so that is why it loads from `application/libraries`.

Simply don't include it in your autoload array()

Also, consider updating your CI version (if you already haven't) to take advantage of the latest security patches / fixes.